# In phpMyAdmin, how can I execute mysqldump query?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, phpmyadmin

I wanted to execute

```
mysqldump -u username -p –all-databases > dump.sql
```

However, I can't see the appropriate field in `PHPMYADMIN`. Where I can do that?

#### SQL error

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The command you posted does not execute from within PHPMYADMIN

That is supposed to be executed in the OS Shell

There are many web pages that explain running a backup of MySQL with PHP

For example, if you go to [How to backup your Mysql database with phpMyAdmin](https://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php), you will learn [how to do the backup starting from the `Export` tab](https://fragments.turtlemeat.com/image2-mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php) as well as doing the mysqldump from the OS.

Comment: Both of these pages are outdated and don't reflect current options, leaving a lot to be inferred which will be confusing for newbies.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 I posted my answer 20 months ago. Please feel free to post new answer to reflect updated options.